# How does one filter a SpatialIndexFeatureCollection?

Tags: java, geotools, opengis

When looking at the documentation for Geotools [FeatureCollection](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/collection.html#performance-options), the subsection on Performance Options notes:

> TreeSetFeatureCollection: the traditional TreeSet implementation used by default.
>
> Note this does not perform well with spatial queries as the contents
>   are not indexed.

Later it recommends a `SpatialIndexFeatureCollection` for faster queries:

> SpatialIndexFeatureCollection: uses a spatial index to hold on to
>   contents for fast visual display in a MapLayer; you cannot add more
>   content to this feature collection once it is used
>
> DataUtilities.source( featureCollection ) will wrap
>   SpatialIndexFeatureCollection in a SpatialIndexFeatureSource that is
>   able to take advantage of the spatial index.

The example given is:

```
final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = 

DataUtilities.createType("location","geom:Point,name:String");
WKTReader2 wkt = new WKTReader2();

SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection();
collection.add( SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( TYPE, new Object[]{ wkt.read("POINT(1,2)"), "name1"} ));
collection.add( SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( TYPE, new Object[]{ wkt.read("POINT(4,4)"), "name1"} ));

// Fast spatial Access
SimpleFeatureSource source = DataUtilities.source( collection );
SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures( filter );
```

Besides not being able to compile this code (`SimpleFeatureCollection` is an interface and does not contain the member `add`), the code for `SpatialIndexFeatureSource.getFeatures(Filter)` directly calls `SpatialIndexFeatureCollection.subCollection(Filter)` which is defined as

```
public SimpleFeatureCollection subCollection(Filter filter) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

[Github](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/13.x/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/collection/SpatialIndexFeatureCollection.java#L127)

Here is an example of my own attempt to use this

```
  FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

  SimpleFeatureCollection answers = getAnswers();
  SpatialIndexFeatureCollection collection = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection();
  collection.addAll(answers);
  SimpleFeatureSource source = DataUtilities.source( collection );

  SimpleFeatureCollection gridCollection = getGridCollection();
  SimpleFeatureIterator iter = gridCollection.features();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature grid = iter.next();
    Geometry gridCell = (Geometry) grid.getDefaultGeometry();
    Filter gridFilter = ff.intersects(ff.property("geometry"), ff.literal(gridCell));

    SimpleFeatureCollection results = source.getFeatures(combinedFilter);
  }
```

Unsurprisingly, this results in a `UnsupportedOperationException`

I have not been able to get this example to work and would really like to take advantage of the spatial indexing. How am I supposed to use a `SpatialIndexFeatureCollection` similar to the above example?

Answer (score 1):

`SpatialIndexFeatureCollection` now implements the subCollection method. See the [PR here](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1113). I haven't had a chance to backport the changes but future releases will now work the way you expected.